# jquery nth-child selector starting from 2 not 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

I meet an extremely bizarre case. With my elements

```
<div class="main-form col-sm-12">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">Update this Ticket?</span>
    </label>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="update-subject" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Subject</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="update-subject" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="update-body" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Body</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="update-body" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="update-email" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email of contact</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="update-email" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Priority</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: none;">
            <select class="form-control col-sm-3" id="update-priority">
                <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                <option value="low">Low</option>
                <option value="high">High</option>
                <option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" style='text-align: center;'>Status</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: none;">
            <select class="form-control col-sm-3" id='update-status'>
                <option value="new">New</option>
                <option value="open">Open</option>
                <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="hold">Hold</option>
                <option value="solved">Solved</option>
                <option value="closed">Closed</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="update-comment" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Comment</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="update-comment" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I check `$('.main-form .form-group:nth-child(4) input')`, it returns nothing instead of 2 `input` elements. I tried running several logs with `$('.main-form .form-group nth-child(n)')`. When it is 1, it returns nothing, the same goest with `first-child`. When it is 2, it returns the first element. When it is 5, it returns the element with two `input` children. When it is 6, it returns the same element with `last-child`. This is totally non-understandable and ridiculous. May anyone help me with this?

Comment: It returns `1`: https://jsfiddle.net/k3rjruk4/

Comment: @BenM It should be `2`

Comment: Which element do you think `.form-grouo:nth-child(4)` matches?

Comment: @BenM The `:nth-child()` CSS selector is not zero based. It states [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) that _Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1_.

Comment: @BenM Starting from top to bottom, the fourth element should be the one containing two `input` - `priority` and `status`

Comment: @BenM Just saw you removed your comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: @necroface The first child of `.form-group:nth-child(4)` is a label element that contains the text "Priority". The next element below that is a div. Inside of that div is an input element. Are you saying this input element is for priority, and that you want the value of this input element?

Comment: @AaronEveleth No. `.form-group:nth-child(4)` actually matches the *Email of contact* row: https://jsfiddle.net/k3rjruk4/1/

Comment: @AaronEveleth When I log `.form-group:nth-child(4)`, it does not even return the fourth `.form-group` (the one with the label "Priority" inside), it returns the third instead

Comment: @AaronEveleth But why does it match that row? Couting from top to bottom, "Email of contact" is definitely indexed 3

Comment: @AaronEveleth I think I've got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `#update-modal` contains child elements that are not `.form-group` elements, you need to use `nth-of-type` instead:

```
$('#update-modal .main-form .form-group:nth-of-type(4) input');
```

For example:

```js
$('#update-modal .main-form .form-group:nth-of-type(4) input').css('background', '#ff00ff')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="update-modal">
<div class="main-form col-sm-12">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">Update this Ticket?</span>
    </label>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="update-subject" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Subject</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="update-subject" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="update-body" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Body</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="update-body" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="update-email" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email of contact</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="update-email" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Priority</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: none;">
            <select class="form-control col-sm-3" id="update-priority">
                <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                <option value="low">Low</option>
                <option value="high">High</option>
                <option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" style='text-align: center;'>Status</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="display: none;">
            <select class="form-control col-sm-3" id='update-status'>
                <option value="new">New</option>
                <option value="open">Open</option>
                <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="hold">Hold</option>
                <option value="solved">Solved</option>
                <option value="closed">Closed</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="update-comment" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Comment</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="update-comment" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand yet. There are still 5 elements with `.form-group` class name. Why did it start from the element indexed at 2 instead of 1? What is the difference?

Comment: To better understand what's happening, try different selectors and it will make sense. For example, log: `$('#update-modal :nth-child(1)')`.